# Xamarin build issue stating The type Zza is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Cant find Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement

Tags: android, xamarin

Im am trying to compile a Xamarin Android project in Visual Studio 2019 but I can't get around this error: Error    CS0012  The type 'Zza' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71f3e3261ac778b5'.

I have verified my version of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement and all references point to 42.10.21.1 and the .dll file is where it should be at ..\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.42.1021.1\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.dll

What am I missing here?  Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Remove the refernce of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement from the project add add again ...To add right click in refernce >Add Refernce > then Browse> then select the refernce